# How to get block device name from partition device name?

Tags: shell-script, partition, block-device

I'm looking for a portable way to obtain parent block device name (e.g. `/dev/sda`) given the partition device name (e.g. `/dev/sda1`). I know I could just drop the last character, but that wouldn't work in some cases:

- MMC card readers typically have names like `/dev/mmcblk0`, while their partitions have names like `/dev/mmcblk0p1` (notice the extra `p`).
- optional: some block devices don't have any partition table at all and are formatted as a single partition. In this case, partition device and parent block device are the same.

LVM volumes are a whole different kettle of fish. I don't need to support them right now, but if taking them into account requires little extra effort, I wouldn't mind.

Comment: How portable? My laptop has its root partition on `/dev/sd0a` but there's no `/dev/sd0` device (there is a `/dev/sd0c`...)

Comment: @don_crissti, `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p1` are Linux-specific anyway. `lsblk` is relatively recent though.

Comment: `lsblk` also uses the device node numbers to find the correct one, instead of just using the name. seems the simplest solution for Linux and util-linux would likely be always available anyway.

Comment: @don_crissti `lsblk -dpno pkname $devname` passed all my tests! Perhaps you should add an answer.

Comment: @thrig Well yeah, I'd definitely expect the script to return `/dev/sd0c` in that case. Do the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're on linux you could use `lsblk` (which is part of `util-linux`):

```
lsblk -no pkname /dev/sda1
```

Comment: My `lsblk` (`util-linux`:2.20.1, Ubuntu 14.04) does not have the `pkname` column, just `kname`.

Comment: @heemayl - it was added _only_ [four years ago](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=310c06035630a83dddfafaca55e5de8d0971a20c) so not available on distros that use older releases...

Comment: `$ lsblk -no pkname /dev/nvme0n1p3` returns 7 lines on my system. Yep, this partition is encrypted, and contains LVM, this is not a trivial situation. I don't know how you're supposed to reliably pickup the right line from a script.

Comment: @elboulangero can you post what the seven lines look like?

Answer (score 21):

If a device is a partition of another device then `/sys/class/block/$dev` will contain a file called `partition` (whose content is the partition number).

If that's the case, you can get the name of the parent device with:

```
basename "$(readlink -f "/sys/class/block/$dev/..")"
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
echo /sys/class/block/$dev(:A:h:t)
```

Example:

```
$ dev=sda1
$ basename "$(readlink -f "/sys/class/block/$dev/..")"
sda
$ dev=nbd0p1
$ basename "$(readlink -f "/sys/class/block/$dev/..")"
nbd0
```

LVM volumes are completely different, they are not *partitions* except in the special case where they are one contiguous `linear` mapping of a physical PV.

If you're in such a case, you can get the name of that PV with:

```
ls "/sys/class/block/$dev/slaves"
```

Where `$dev` is something like `dm-2` (which you can obtain from `"$(basename "$(readlink -f /dev/VG/LV)")"`).

Comment: I have accepted don_crissti's answer because I happen to have `lsblk` and the syntax is short, but I acknowledge that your answer is more generic and portable. Thanks!